# Segmentation fault - How to write and read a linked list from a pipe

Tags: c, linux, list

I have an array of integers and i have to determine on which indexes it could be found a given value using P processes. I split the vector so that each process can search for that value in a subvector and write on the pipe the indexes. A process can find that value on multiple positions and i am using a simple linked list to store the indexes for each process. After that i am writing on the pipe. My problem is that the reading is partial and i get Segmentation fault, because the sizeof the list is bigger than i am declaring it. How can i do this to work?

```
struct Node;
typedef struct Node{
   int val;
   struct Node *next;
}Node;


static int elementsList[] = {   1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,3,10,11,12,3,14,15,16,17,
            1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,
            1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,3,11,12,13,14,3,16,17,
            1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,
            1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,3   };



//method called by a process to check for the value in a subvector
void getPosition(int elemList[],int start,int step, int size, int value,int wPipe ){
    Node *first = NULL;
    Node *current;
    Node *temp;
    int i;

    for(i = start; i < size ; i += step){
        if(value == elemList[i]){
           current = (Node*) malloc (sizeof(Node));
           current->val = i;
           if(first == NULL){
               first = current;
               first->next = NULL;
           }else{
               temp = first;
               while(temp->next != NULL){
                  temp = temp->next;
               }
               current->next = NULL;
               temp->next = current;
           }
        }
    }
    write(wPipe,&first,sizeof(Node) );
  }
 int main(){

  //fork() the P processes
  for(child = 0; child < P ; child++){
     if((pid[child] = fork()) < 0){
         perror("fork");
         exit(1);
     }

     else if(pid[child] == 0){
        close(fd[0]);
        printf("Child #%d\n",getpid());

        //call getPositions(...) method

        getPosition(elementsList,child,P,SIZE,valueToFind,fd[1]);
        close(fd[1]);
        exit(0);
     }

 }



  //read form the pipe and print the positions
  Node *temp = NULL;
  for(child = 0; child < P; child++){
     temp = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
     nbytes = read(fd[0],&temp, sizeof(Node));
        while(temp != NULL){
            printf("Position: %d\n",temp->val);
            temp = temp->next;
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can't send pointers to another process. Processes have separate virtual memory maps, an address valid in one process is not valid in another.

Comment: I am using fork() so the entire virtual address space of the parent should be replicated in the child process. Or i am getting this wrong?

Comment: Once the processes are working independently, they could be using the same address for different purposes. Basically, don't pass addresses between processes unless the data is in shared memory that is mapped to the same address in both processes. You need to write the integer indexes (only) to the pipe, and read them off the pipe. Your code indentation leaves somewhat to be desired. It is hard to tell by looking at your code whether there's a single function here or multiple functions. It would be better if you posted an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).

Comment: `static int elementsList[] = {}; // some values` - *what values?*

Comment: I am sorry for my code indentation. i tried to fix it. I have tried to write and read only the indexes, but i had the same problem, because one process could write multiple times on the pipe (more than one index in his subvector) and i don't have any idea how to notify the read that it's getting more data from one single process. That's why i have thought on sending the indexes like a linked list.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler write an answer to can accept it. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once the processes are working independently, they could be using the same address for different purposes. Basically, don't pass addresses between processes unless the data is in shared memory that is mapped to the same address in both processes. You need to write the integer indexes (only) to the pipe, and read them off the pipe.

This dramatically simplifies the code you need:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static int elementsList[] =
{
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 3, 10, 11, 12, 3, 14, 15, 16, 17,
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 3, 11, 12, 13, 14, 3, 16, 17,
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 3
};
enum { SIZE = sizeof(elementsList)/sizeof(elementsList[0]) };

// method called by a process to check for the value in a subvector
static void getPosition(int elemList[], int start, int step, int size, int value, int wPipe)
{
    for (int i = start; i < size; i += step)
    {
        if (value == elemList[i])
            write(wPipe, &i, sizeof(i));
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    enum { P = 5 };
    pid_t pid[P];
    int fd[2];
    int valueToFind = 3;

    pipe(fd);


    for (int child = 0; child < P; child++)
    {
        if ((pid[child] = fork()) < 0)
        {
            perror("fork");
            exit(1);
        }
        else if (pid[child] == 0)
        {
            close(fd[0]);
            printf("Child #%d\n", getpid());
            getPosition(elementsList, child, P, SIZE, valueToFind, fd[1]);
            close(fd[1]);
            exit(0);
        }
    }

    // read from the pipe and print the positions
    close(fd[1]);
    int index;
    int n = 0;
    printf("Seeking: %d\n", valueToFind);
    while (read(fd[0], &index, sizeof(index)) == sizeof(index))
        printf("%2d: Position: %2d (%d)\n", ++n, index, elementsList[index]);

    return 0;
}
```

Note that it is crucial that the parent process closes the write end of the pipe before going into the loop.

Sample output:

```
Child #55829
Child #55830
Child #55831
Child #55832
Child #55833
Seeking: 3
 1: Position: 70 (3)
 2: Position: 36 (3)
 3: Position:  2 (3)
 4: Position: 12 (3)
 5: Position:  8 (3)
 6: Position: 43 (3)
 7: Position: 48 (3)
 8: Position: 53 (3)
 9: Position: 19 (3)
10: Position: 84 (3)
```